# How to create a (CSS) style variant for a dropdown widget, to target its list rows with it?

Tags: google-app-maker

as the title states, I need to create a 'Compact' style variant for a dropdown widget. But I can't figure out how to target the dropdown items (rows) with it.
This works to target all the dropdowns:

```
.app-Dropdown-Item {  
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Here's how I've tried to do it with the style variant to target only specific widgets:

```
.app-Dropdown--Compact .app-Dropdown-Item {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

This has worked for me before, like with Tabs-widget's header:

```
.app-Tabs--RedBg .app-Tabs-Header {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

I would suspect it could have something to do with the list items being not immediate sub-items of the dropdown widget, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible to create custom style variants for dropdown items at this time... So, the only way to style dropdown items individually is to write style for particular dropdown:

```css
.app-PageName-DropdownName-List > .app-Dropdown-Item {
  padding: 0px; /* it seems that this rule works without !important */
}
```

Comment: Why can't he just do:

.app-Dropdown--Compact > .app-Dropdown-Item {
  padding: 0px; /* it seems that this rule works without !important */
}

Edit: Never mind, I think I understand. Ideally there should also be a .app-Dropdown-List--Compact. I'll look into this and see if we already do this, if not sounds like a reasonable feature request.